# USB stick 8GB working when plugged to TV, doesn’t work on any PC

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have strange problem. My USB storage when plugged to TV (Samsung) is working fine I have access to data on stick. Problem starts when try to plug to PC it’s not recognised by windows – no size, can’t format or do anything. I already tried to recovery software but no luck.
Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: What type of USB is it?

Comment: What do you mean with "already tried to recovery software"?

Comment: And first of all! What os are u using? How you doesn't working looks like, do you get any error codes or screenshots? What did you found by yourself with google?

Comment: Basically when I plug in to TV USB I can watch pictures, movies from stick bu when plug in to PC nothing. In my computer it aper external disc as drive E:\ but I can't access. Properties shown 0kB disc I can't format stick basically I can't do anything with it. I tried "M3 Data Recovery", "M3 RAW Drive Recovery", few other software and tricks but computer doesn't have access to this drive - so how TV has??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the stick works fine on the TV (which often use linux-based operating systems) and does not work in Windows, I would guess it is a partitioning issue.

Use some partitioning tool (e.g., gparted or Partition Master) and check the partitioning.

Things to look for:

- MBR or GUID Partition table
- Partition TYPE (maybe the TV formated the stick as ext3 or something similar that windows can not read)
- partition layout (Many versions of Windows, or all?, have problems recognizing other than the first partition of a USB stick)
- is the partition non-active or hidden?
- You should also try to use a Linux live CD to have a closer look at the stick. If this does not work, it might be a hardware problem.